# div's border doesn't reach parent div's top with 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have this css code:

```
.parent {
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #383838;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #767676;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {        
display: inline-block;
border-left: solid white 1px;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
right: 0px;
top: 7px;
}
```

I want to make the border of `.child` to stretch the entire height of `.parent`, but with the above codes it leaves an irritating gap at the top (it does reach the bottom though). I tried to fix it by setting negative margin and setting line-height to 0 but it messed up the text inside `.child`. Is there a proper way to fix this?

Comment: Plz add **jsfiddle** link. It will be easier for others to help u.

Comment: `top:7px;` moves your div down, (by 7 px)

Comment: That's because you have `top:7px` for .child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `top: 7px` as it positions the child 7px down with respect to the parent.

```css
.parent {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #383838;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #767676;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px white solid;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  right: 0;
  /* top: 7px; Remove this */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
}
.parent {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #383838;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #767676;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:0px;
}
.child {
  border-left: solid white 1px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You have to normalize the css then everything will work fine.